# How to skip json object (from json array) in android if it has an empty/null value?

Tags: android, json

I'm developing an app where user can get list of other users, but i have to skip the users if they dont have completed their profile

ok take a look at my code:

```
Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
                        while (keys.hasNext()) {
                            String key = keys.next();
                            JSONObject js = json.optJSONObject(key);
                            if (js != null) {
                                String user_info = js.getString("user_info");
                                user.setInfo(user_info);
                            } else {

                            }
                        }
```

what should i do in (else)

heres my json:

```
 "users": [
{
  "id": 73,
  "name": "Name",
  "lastname": "Lastname",
  "email": "",
  "create_date": 1469874203
},
{
  "id": 73,
  "name": "Name",
  "lastname": "Lastname",
  "email": "",
  "create_date": 1469874203
  "profile"{
           "address": string...
           "avatar": url...
      }

},
```

something like that

Comment: Are you using GSON library to parse android?

Comment: no, i'm not using it

Comment: `js.equalsIgnoreCase("")`  try this maybe help you

Comment: json doesn't support equalsIgnoreCase(""), its for the keys. and it didn't work. but thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");
if(jsonArray.lenght() > 0){
    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        if(object.has("profile")){
            Iterator<String> keys = object.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(key)){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    User user = new User();
                    //parse and save user details
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your if condition. Have you checked it?

Comment: of course i did, but it still gets me the users, but without "user_info" only

Comment: can you post your json please?

Comment: so you want to get user only if it has a "profile"  JSONObject right?

Comment: i tried it, it still shows the users without profiles + not showing profiles of other users

Comment: hey thanx @Megha Maniar, its kind of worked but instead of NOT showing the profiless users now its showing just blanks/just their space. How to solve this

Comment: I am glad to know that it helped.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by using this code,

```
if (myObject.has("object_name") && !myObject.isNull("object_name")) {
    // Consider this user.
  }else{
    // Avoid this user.
  }
```

Also you can directly check the null by `myObject.isNull("object_name")` in if block.
Hope this helps!

Comment: thanx, i already tried that, it still shows me the users, but with empty value just their names